# INDEX MATCH Product code The INDEX in Both Sheets

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match, formulas

I hope you can help. I have researched a solution but found none that satisfied my problem.

This issue I am facing is this. In Pic 1 you can see that C000004 is my Customer and he has the number 7 in Cell D16. Underneath C000004 you can see more numbers 426, 5062, 5063 etc these are my Product codes on Sheet named **New Piv**

In Pic 2 you can see I am on a new sheet **ROI RUBU Schema** and in Column A you can see again my Product Codes. Also in Pic 2 you can see from Cells D1 to L1 we have the numbers 1 to 9

Now what I would like to happen is that if a number from Cells D1 to L1 on sheet **ROI RUBU Schema** is present in Cell D16 **New Piv** in my example it is 7.

Then I need the formula to recognize Product code 4626 in A17 on sheet **New Piv** and the product code 4626 in A37 **ROI RUBU Schema** and that 7 is in J1 on **ROI RUBU Schema**  and that 7 is in D16 on **New Piv** and return the % value in Cell D17 **New Piv**

In Pic 2 you can see a colored line showing that I would need 0% returned in Cell D17 in **New Piv**

Also in Pic 2 you can see another colored line that if the number 3 was present in D17 **New Piv** product code 5062 then I would expect the result in D18 **New Piv** to be 8%

Essentially what ever number ends up in D16 **New Piv** I need the percentage vale for the product code from **ROI RUBU Schema** brought in from **ROI RUBU Schema** to the product code in **New Piv**

The formula I have tried is `=INDEX('ROI RUBU Schema'!A1:L92,MATCH('New Piv'!D16,'ROI RUBU Schema'!D1:L1,0))`

But I have had no luck. As always any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Pic 1
[image]

Pic 2

[image]

Comment: You haven't specified the column no. in your formula. Try adding column no FYR: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/13/excel-index-match-function-vlookup/

Comment: @Linga: Thank you for taking the time to respond: I have added the Column to the formula `=INDEX('ROI RUBU Schema'!A$1:L$92,MATCH('New Piv'!D$16,'ROI RUBU Schema'!D$1:L$1,0),10)` But unfortunately still no joy. However the Formula is now returning 32% in D17 of Pic 1 and if I change the number to 3 in D16 I get Product Specific Rebate so I think it is counting down the rows.... I think the problem with the formula is at no point is the Product codes in Pic 1 referenced in the formula... again any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Try changing the array range from A1:L92 to A3:L92

Answer (score 1):

So thank you for the help, I got there in the end and I hope this helps someone else out. 
The formula that works for me is `=INDEX('ROI RUBU Schema'!$D:$L,MATCH(A17,'ROI RUBU Schema'!$A:$A,0),MATCH(D$16,'ROI RUBU Schema'!$D$1:L$1,0))`

Hope it helps and love the site :-)